# How to control a segment of sequence alignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, alignment

I would like to compare two sequences with a given "window of alignment", ie if the sequences are similar in a stretch of five or more.

For example:

```
A = "CCCTCGTTGCTAAAAA"
B = "CCCAGCAACGAAAAAA"
```

I would like to mark a hit on the matrix for only the last 5 characters

For now i am stuck with something like that:

```
import numpy as np


A = "CCCTCGTTGCTAAAAA"
B = "CCCAGCAACGAAAAAA"
n1 = len(A)
n2 = len(B)
data = np.zeros(shape=(n2, n1), dtype=np.int)

for i in range(n2):
for j in range(n1):
    if A[i:i+4] == B[j:j+4]:
        data[i:i+4,j:j+4] = 1
print data
```

Thanks for any help

Using python 2.7.3

Comment: I'm not a bioinfo guy, but everytime I see a few codons, the very first library that comes to my mind is [BioPython](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html). You should definitely take a look at it, specially at the [Parsing Examples](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc10).

Comment: Are you looking for a faster algorithm, or just a cleaner way to do it? You could trim off about 8n tests by using range(n - 4) (because you can't match a window of 5 over fewer than 5 codons), and xrange() will give you a more memory-efficient iterator.

You might be able to do better using dictionaries to create a lookup of all distinct 5-element substrings in A, with a list of their start points, then look up each 5-element substring in B against that table. That will give you all of the points in A where your current substring from B matches.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will also try to check this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below, is a functioning example. Take note of the +5 rather than the +4, since list slicing with Python from i:i+1 means one character is requested. Additionally, n1 and n2 can be decreased since there is no point in checking the part which is shorter than 5 characters.

```
import numpy as np


A = "CCCTCGTTGCTAAAAA"
B = "CCCAGCAACGAAAAAA"
n1 = len(A) - 4
n2 = len(B) - 4
data = np.zeros(shape=(n2, n1), dtype=np.int)


for i in range(n2):
    for j in range(n1):
        if A[i:i+5] == B[j:j+5]:
            data[i:i+5,j:j+5] = 1
print(data)
```

With this code you get two hits, once for the "CCCAGCAACG**AAAAA**A" with the last part of string A and once for the "CCCAGCAACGA**AAAAA**", also with the last part of string A.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did not think about it this way, thank you. However, the final result on the matrix should enter 1 in every hit if the condition is met. Meanwhile we got hit only for last nucleotide.